# Where's my issue here? (PHP/PDO) - User exist

Tags: php, pdo

trying to check whether a user exists or not via pdo

```
$wantedusrnm = $_POST['new-usrnm'];
$userExist1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:wantedusrnm";
$userExist = $handler->prepare($userExist1);
$userExist->execute(array(':username' => $wantedusrnm));
$userExist = ($userExist->rowCount());
```

for some reason it errors, dunno why, any reasons?

Comment: Replace `:wantedusrnm` by `:username` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
$userExist->execute(array(':username' => $wantedusrnm));
```

To:

```
$userExist->execute(array(':wantedusrnm' => $wantedusrnm));
```

Because, in your query you've got `:wantedusrnm` but in your execution array you've got `:username`.